# Compare dates in jsx

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I am trying to display events for the same day by comparing dates.

How can I use a conditional statement in my map?

```
{events && events.length && events.map((event) => <Text>{event.author} 

      { 
          (currentDay == date)
            ?  'same' 
            :  'different' 
      }

      </Text>)
}
```

How would be the best way to do this?

Comment: https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/blob/master/src/components/DateRangePicker.jsx

Comment: You have mapped to a variable `event` but are then using two undefined variables `currentDay` and `date`...

Comment: Assuming you're somehow defining currentDay even though you're not doing anything with event.... `currentDay.getTime() === date.getTime()`

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `isSame` from momentjs

```
moment(currentDay).isSame(date, 'day')
```

If you need to do a lot of checks to do in your `map`, remember you can write it like this as well

```
events.map((event) => {
  const text = // your conditional stuff
  // some more code if necessary
  return (
    <Text>{text}</Text>
  )
}
```